# How to create a collection inside a document in Firestore with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with a document and I want to create an empty collection inside the document.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc("thisdoc). ??? (create collection inside this document)
```

I don't know what to add instead of ???

Comment: "I want to create an empty collection". You cannot create a collection without creating at least one document. The collection is actually created when the first document is created.

Comment: Ok thank you, that's not very smart because I'd like to create and empty collection and later let the users create documents inside of It. I'll try to create sample document

Comment: You don't really need to pre-create a collection. Just create a new document under any collection (or sub-collection) you want to create and.. voilà! the collection AND the doc exist.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#adding-documents) will help you there.

**NOTE** The Firebase team is migrating these docs onto firebase.com directly, so this link may get old quickly in the next months.

EDIT. Since you need to create it under a subcollection, simply:

1. Take a reference of that document
2. Reference a subcollection in that document, *even if it doesn't exist, yet*
3. Create a first document in there, and your subcollection is made.

Pseudocode:

```dart
// WARN, PSEUDOCODE AHEAD

final documentRef = firestore.collection("myCol").document("myDoc");
final subCollectRef = documentRef.collection("mySubCol");

subCollectRef.add({
            'your': 'data',
          });
```

Comment: This will add a new document, not a new collection inside an existing document

Comment: Sorry, I took a middle concept for granted, I edited and updated my answer. Please upvote / accept it if you found it useful.

Comment: Thank you. Can I add blank data e.g. '':''?

Comment: Yes, you can add an empty document in root collections as well!